# How to do rync backup and then upload at different times of day

Tags: rsync

I have around 100GB of data which i want to backup on remote FTP.

Now i think it will take around 2-3 week to upload as i have upload speed around 100KB/s.

Now i can't do that continuously.

Is it possible that rync strtuploading from 8PM to 6AM so that it uploads after work hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this with rsync, you can also enable compression with rsync to get more out of your pipe at the cost of CPU Load, these are the options for compression from the man page:

```
-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
    --compress-level=NUM    explicitly set compression level
    --skip-compress=LIST    skip compressing files with suffix in LIST
```

So, you can set it up to compress .html files, while not compressing .jpg's ( since they are already compressed and this will just eat cycles )

As for the time period you're specifying, just run rsync from cron starting at 8pm, something like:

```
0 20 * * *  rsync -av --compress --skip-compress=jpg,mp3,mpeg /source /dest
```

Then run kill from cron at 6am - if this is the only rsync process running on this server - something like this:

```
0 6 * * * killall rsync
```

Please note these are just examples of how you can do this, they don't include any sanity checks of any sort.  They should work in a basic environment as long as nothing else interferes, but I would not consider it a robust solution...

Comment: I use -avz option is that good

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty common set of options, and it should work fine for what you're attempting to do here.  If the CPU load starts to be a problem you should also use the --skip-compress option to exclude compression on any binary or already compressed files which may be getting backed up.  Like MySQL DBs, pics, and movies.

Comment: according to the rsync man page, the value for `--skip-compress` should be a list of extensions separated by **slashes**, i.e. `--skip-compress=jpg/mp3/mpeg`.